# Centralise TableLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

I had a TableLayout and wanted to centralise it in a ScrollView. With the following code, the table was centralised as seen in the design view, but did not work on the Emulator or on the phone.

```
   <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
                <TableLayout
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="*">
                ....
                </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

On preview mode, it looks like this:
[image]

But on the emulator, the text is not centralized:
[image]

I have tried 2 things:

1. wrap TableLayout with a LinearLayout
2. replace ScrollView with RelativeLayout and set
   `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

but the outcome were the same (works in Android Studio, did not work on emulator/phone). Is there something that I missed out?

Comment: Maybe you're running an old build, clean and rebuild.

Comment: "works in Android Studio, did not work on emulator/phone" do you mean it worked with the android emulator in android studio?

Comment: Can you provide 2 screenshots of 'what I see in preview' and 'what I get on emulators'?

Comment: oh..ok he meant the preview.

Comment: @aclokay tried that without success

Comment: @LucaNicoletti uploaded the screenshots

Comment: table layout is wrap content, so it won't expand with parent height, change it :) that should work

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, it does not work. Anyway, I want to centralize the TableLayout, so  wrap_content and android:gravity="center_vertical" should be correct